# Rolling back a merge in Git

Tags: xcode, git

My coworker was on one branch, I was on the other.  When she merged her branch with mine, my changes did not get in.  The source files were "M" (Modified) in Xcode and not "C" (Conflict) so we assumed it was ok.  I went back to my branch and I saw that the the code I changed was still there and my code was working fine.  Then we thought to try the merge again but being on my branch from my desktop.  Same thing showed up where the files were "M" and none were "C".

Again my changes got overriden.  So now I'm trying to go back a merge.  I tried using the Github tool I downloaded from http://mac.github.com/ by clicking on the most recent commit, and rolling back to that commit, but my changes still seemed to be gone.  I do not see the merging of the branches in the history.  Is that because I haven't committed after merging?

How can I get back to my branch before I merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Xcode's version control GUI nor Github tool. If you know the sha1 of the commit which had your changes, you can do this at the command line:

```
git reset --hard <the sha1>
```

That will reset your current branch to be at your commit. It will also reset the files in the working tree. Be careful. If you have uncommitted changes, they will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the last n number of unpushed commits(commited yet but not pushed). Then command you need to use is

```
git reset HEAD  -- will omit the last commit
git reset HEAD^n  -- will omit the n number of last unpushed commits.
```

Comment: As far as a I remember the first one must be `git reset HEAD^` (which is just a shortcut for `HEAD^1`). With `git reset HEAD` you'll tell git to set the branch HEAD to HEAD

Comment: Yes its currect , i just missed.